# Create anchor without hitest or trackables occured fatal error

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

**status.cc:153 generic::failed_precondition:
ARCoreError:third_party/arcore/ar/core/session.cc@1668
Cannot create anchor.**

```
   private  void drawVector(Vector3  objVector){
    Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();
    if (frame == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (frame.getCamera().getTrackingState() != TrackingState.TRACKING) {
        return;
    }
    float[] position=new float[]{(float)objVector.x,(float)objVector.y,(float)objVector.z};
    Pose pose=new Pose(position,new float[]{0,0,0,1});
    Session session=arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
// the error occuer here
    **Anchor anchor=session.createAnchor(pose);**  
    anchorsCollec.add(anchor);
    AnchorNode anchorNode=new AnchorNode(anchor);
    anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
    // Create the transformable andy and add it to the anchor.
    TransformableNode andy = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
    andy.setParent(anchorNode);
    andy.setRenderable(andyRenderable);
}

    //start arSession
onStart() {
Scene.OnUpdateListener onUpdateListener=frameTime->{
drawVector(new Vector3(1,1,1))
}
 scene.addOnUpdateListener(onUpdateListener);
}
```

Comment: have you debugged the code?

Comment: add complete stacktrace.

Comment: @NoumanCh   i dont konw what happened . it worked out today. i suspected too many anchors  were created in same place. thanks，bro

Comment: happy to hear that it worked lol.